# Uncaught TypeError paper-dialog polymer

Tags: javascript, html, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

so i am trying to get paper-dialog to show up once i click on a FAB but i get this error,

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined

Paper dialog

```
<paper-dialog id="dialog1">
              <p>{{item.name}}</p>
</paper-dialog>
```

paper-FAB

```
<paper-fab icon="shopping-cart" title="hire" on-click="hire"></paper-fab>
```

script

```
hire: function(e){
            this.$$['#dialog1'].toggle();
            console.log("click");
          }
```

Comment: FYI: The error message is saying that `this.$$['#dialog1']` evaluates to `undefined`.

Comment: yes i understand the error, i've gone through a whole bunch of docs and stack overflow questions on how paper-dialog normally works, however i do not understand why this produces a error

Comment: try `this.$.dialog1.toggle();`

Comment: @SG_ that was my initial try/code but still the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `this.$['...']` only works inside of a registered polymer component. I'm guessing you're trying to use it inside a `dom-repeat`.

Try creating an component instead, and it will work.

See: http://jsbin.com/gubesa/edit?html,output